# Creating Item Template in Visual Studio 2012 with multiple, non-nested files

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2012

I'm looking to create a new Visual Studio 2012 Item Template that generates five files, three of which are nested, one which isn't. It should look like this:

```
MyView1.View
   MyView1.view.cs
   MyView1.data.cs
   MyView1.gen.cs

MyView1.js
```

(The reason I need the JavaScript file separate is due to an issue with using it as an embedded resource to pull out dynamically for parsing at runtime.)

This is the template file I have come up with so far:

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
<TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>MyView.view</DefaultName>
    <Name>MVC Desktop View - Integration Test</Name>
    <Description>A view in a MVC-based desktop web application for use in integration tests.</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
    <NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>1</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
</TemplateData>
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.view" ReplaceParameters="true">Template.view</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.view.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Template.view.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.data.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Template.data.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.gen.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Template.gen.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.js" ReplaceParameters="true" ItemType="Embedded Resource">Template.js</ProjectItem>
</TemplateContent>
<WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>VisualStudio.TemplateWizards, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87390d63f27c23a4</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>VisualStudio.TemplateWizards.ViewItemTemplateWizard</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
```

The problem is that the JavaScript file is nested underneath the .View file and I can't seem to find a way around that. I ideally want this to be a single Item Template that is added (and not have to use two separate item templates).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have everything else working, just need to polish up this last little piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this. It turns out that when adding ItemType as an attribute to a file, you can't use the name of the Item Type as shown in the dropdown (according to this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/3f6788cd-634b-42e5-ba63-b6dc52af71f9). Changing the line to this (no space between Embedded and Resource) solves the problem:

```
<ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.js" ReplaceParameters="true" ItemType="EmbeddedResource">Template.js</ProjectItem>
```

Comment: Are you sure? ItemType="EmbeddedResource" controls the treatment of the file at compile time, and has no influence that I know of on the nesting in solution explorer. [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884732/nested-files-in-item-template) worked for me.